# How i pass incoming call phonenumber to main activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I create a simple application for get incoming call number, work and show me the number with toast but i want to pass this variable to my main activity for processing...example send sms when call administrator number.I try this code but no data display in my UI...any idea?Help for this?

```
   public class IncomingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

            if(null == bundle)
                    return;

            Log.i("IncomingCallReceiver",bundle.toString());

            String state = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

            Log.i("IncomingCallReceiver","State: "+ state);

            if(state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))
            {
                    String phonenumber = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

                    Log.i("IncomingCallReceiver","Incomng Number: " + phonenumber);

                    String info = "Detect Calls sample application\nIncoming number: " + phonenumber;



                    Intent intentsend=new Intent("update");//Send data to update UI
                    intentsend.putExtra( "data","Admin call..."+info);
                    context.sendBroadcast(intentsend);

                    Toast.makeText(context, info, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

and my main activity is....

```
     @Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

     updateReceiver=new BroadcastReceiver() {
          @Override
          public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intentsend) {
              //get extras, do some stuff
            String data = intentsend.getStringExtra("data");

            textphone.setText(data);

          }
      };
      IntentFilter updateIntentFilter=new IntentFilter("update");
      registerReceiver(updateReceiver, updateIntentFilter);
}
```

Comment: use startActivity instead of sendBroadcast for starting Activity when call appear on device

Comment: Need some delay before use intent send to UI?

Comment: You could send me code for this?

Comment: i think it's not possible because Broadcast time is very less but you can put some delay in Activity before showing the UI elements

Comment: or you can use IntentService for starting Activity . the logic is : first start IntentService from BroadcastReceiver when call appear , inside IntentService put delay in onhandleintent method before starting Activity.

Comment: If the user want close the apk ,after x no answer call must close x activities?

Comment: @AntonisKan what is the objective of doing this, can you tell us what u are trying to achieve?

Comment: Ok.Thanks.I think not needed the text in main activity.I use only the service...send sms the location after admin making call...

Answer (score 0):

I think that your activity is not visible when the phone is ringing, since the phone application is popup and your activity is put in the pause state.

You cannot do the logic inside the Receiver? or maybe inside a Service?

Comment: What you suggest for show the number in main activity after stop ringing?

Comment: I think i must call a service for send sms after admin call...but how i send to ui?

Answer (score 0):

1) declare this receiver as an inner class of ur activity.  like below, also add an condition if onReceive getting same intent u are broadcasting

```
       class  updateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver() {
          @Override
          public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intentsend) {
              //get extras, do some stuff
            String data = intentsend.getStringExtra("data");

            textphone.setText(data);

          }
      };
```